# TFLite On-device saving signature function crashes

Tags: python, kotlin, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I'm attempting to learn how to implement on-device training for a school project, however I've stumbled on a roadblock. The signature function for saving crashes the app, the other signature functions like train and infer work just fine. The guide I'm using is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/on_device_training/overview).

Basically, I'm trying to personalize the model by training, then saving the model but whenever I attempt to save the model, the app crashes on launch. Any guides on how to save a model in Android after training on device?

Edit: I hope adding the code helps clear some confusion.
-------Code used to save the model------

```
SAVED_MODEL_DIR = "saved_model"

tf.saved_model.save(
    m,
    SAVED_MODEL_DIR,
    signatures={
        'train':
            m.train.get_concrete_function(),
        'infer':
            m.infer.get_concrete_function(),
        'save':
            m.save.get_concrete_function(),
        'restore':
            m.restore.get_concrete_function(),
    })

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(SAVED_MODEL_DIR)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,  
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS 
]

converter.experimental_enable_resource_variables = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

-------Code to save Model in Android (Kotlin)------

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Interpreter(modelPath()).use { interpreter ->
            val outputFile = File(filesDir, "model.tflite")
            val inputs: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
            inputs["checkpoint_path"] = outputFile.absolutePath
            val outputs: Map<String, Any> = HashMap()
            interpreter.runSignature(inputs, outputs, "save")
        }
    }

    private fun modelPath(): File {
        val file = File(this.filesDir, "model.tflite")
        if (file.exists() && file.length() > 0) {
            return file
        }
        this.applicationContext.assets.open("model.tflite").use { f ->
            FileOutputStream(file).use { os ->
                val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
                var read: Int
                while (f.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, read)
                }
                os.flush()
            }
            return file
        }
    }
}
```

-------Model Code------
It's the same model from the TFLite on device training guide.

```
class Model(tf.Module):

  def __init__(self):
    self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE), name='flatten'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='dense_1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, name='dense_2')
    ])

    self.model.compile(
        optimizer='sgd',
        loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

  # The `train` function takes a batch of input images and labels.
  @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec([None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE], tf.float32),
      tf.TensorSpec([None, 10], tf.float32),
  ])
  def train(self, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      prediction = self.model(x)
      loss = self.model.loss(y, prediction)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.model.trainable_variables)
    self.model.optimizer.apply_gradients(
        zip(gradients, self.model.trainable_variables))
    result = {"loss": loss}
    return result

  @tf.function(input_signature=[
      tf.TensorSpec([None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE], tf.float32),
  ])
  def infer(self, x):
    logits = self.model(x)
    probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1)
    return {
        "output": probabilities,
        "logits": logits
    }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
  def save(self, checkpoint_path):
    tensor_names = [weight.name for weight in self.model.weights]
    tensors_to_save = [weight.read_value() for weight in self.model.weights]
    tf.raw_ops.Save(
        filename=checkpoint_path, tensor_names=tensor_names,
        data=tensors_to_save, name='save')
    return {
        "checkpoint_path": checkpoint_path
    }

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=[], dtype=tf.string)])
  def restore(self, checkpoint_path):
    restored_tensors = {}
    for var in self.model.weights:
      restored = tf.raw_ops.Restore(
          file_pattern=checkpoint_path, tensor_name=var.name, dt=var.dtype,
          name='restore')
      var.assign(restored)
      restored_tensors[var.name] = restored
    return restored_tensors
```

---

[This is the output after running the app, however there isn't much to see because the app crashes instantly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5liq2.png)

Comment: Can you add the code you are trying to run and the complete error you get?

Comment: @СергейКох,  I added all the Kotlin code and the code to save the model in Python so that it is easier to see the full picture.

Comment: @karatekraft I don't even get an error log in the terminal, the app just crashes whenever I run intrepreter.runsignature(inputs, outputs, "save"). I added a picture of the output after running the app and you can see that there aren't any error logs, the app just crashes on whenever the save signature function is called.